# remove videoid from youtube api output

Tags: php, youtube-api

Im using the youtube api to search for videos. My issue is that when a search is completed, the output from the search is

```
video_name  video_id
```

I just want it to show

```
video_name
```

heres my code to display search results

```
 $client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);


$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

try {

$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => $_GET['q'],
  'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
));

$videos = '';
$channels = '';
$playlists = '';

// Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
// matching videos, channels, and playlists.
foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
 $imgsrc="<img src=http://img.youtube.com/vi/".$searchResult['id']
               ['videoId']."/hqdefault.jpg height=125 width=125>";
  switch ($searchResult['id']['kind']) {  
    case 'youtube#video':  
      $videos .= sprintf('<li>'.$imgsrc.' %s (%s)</li>', $searchResult['snippet']['title'],  
        $searchResult['id']['videoId']."<a href=/video.php?".$searchResult['id']['videoId']." target=_blank>   Watch This Video</a>");  
      break;
```

Comment: Can you show an example of actual output please?

Comment: Michael Jackson - Man In The Mirror (Original Clip) (F9Nh84lfvW0 Watch This Video)

Where i would like the output to be

Michael Jackson - Man In The Mirror (Original Clip) ( Watch This Video)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `sprintf` but you want to remove `$searchResult['id']['videoId']` without breaking your code. I'd suggest wrapping it in between a particular string e.g `vidid[".$searchResult['id']['videoId']."]` and then remove all content between `vidid[` and `]`. Probably not the best way to go about it though :p

Comment: Ah perfect! Worked like a charm!
Submit it as a answer so i can pick it as an answer for you

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with `sprintf` but you want to remove

`$searchResult['id']['videoId']`

without breaking your code.

I'd suggest wrapping it in between a particular string e.g.

`vidid[".$searchResult['id']['videoId']."]`

and then remove all content between `vidid[` and `]`.